# Js mysql query not using boolean value given with GET request

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to search the **MySQL** database for *active* or *inactive* users that have the value isActive, the idea is that a **GET request** is sent with either `isActive=true` or `isActive=false` and all users that are active or inactive will be sent in the response. The problem is that the `isActive` value is not being used, I can only get it to work by hardcoding it into the SQL query.

When I send a request with the `firstName` value defined it does work, so I think it might have to do with the `isActive` being a `boolean` and not converting correctly but I have not been able to fix that.

Also, I'm using **MySQL2** for the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    getUsers: (req, res, next) => {
        const queryParams = req.query
        logger.debug(queryParams)

        let { firstName, isActive } = req.query
        
        let queryString = 'SELECT * FROM `user`'
        if (firstName || isActive) {
            queryString += ' WHERE '
            if (firstName) {
                queryString += '`firstName` LIKE ?'
                firstName = '%' + firstName + '%'
            }
            if (firstName && isActive) queryString += ' AND '
            if (isActive) {
                queryString += '`isActive` = ?'
            }
        }
        queryString += ';'
        logger.debug(`queryString = ${queryString}`)

        dbconnection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) next(err) // not connected!

            // Use the connection
            connection.query(queryString, [firstName, isActive], function (error, results) {
                    // When done with the connection, release it.
                    connection.release()

                    // Handle error after the release.
                    if (error) next(error)

                    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
                    logger.debug('#results = ', results.length)
                    res.status(200).json({
                        status: 200,
                        results: results,
                    })
                }
            )
        })
    },
```

Here are the logs of when I call the **GET method**:

```
2022-05-20T14:16:12Z [DEBUG] user.controller.js:66 : { isActive: 'false' }
2022-05-20T14:16:12Z [DEBUG] user.controller.js:83 : queryString = SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `isActive` = ?;
2022-05-20T14:16:13Z [DEBUG] dbconnection.js:23 : Connected to database '2186751'
2022-05-20T14:16:13Z [DEBUG] dbconnection.js:27 : Connection 46 acquired
2022-05-20T14:16:13Z [DEBUG] dbconnection.js:31 : Connection 46 released
2022-05-20T14:16:13Z [DEBUG] user.controller.js:97 : #results =  0
```

What the `firstName` and `isActive` are defined as in the **MySQL** database:

```
  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't use strings for booleans, it uses the numbers 1 and 0. So you need to convert the parameters to their corresponding boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from `true/false` to `1/0` for MySQL to understand the boolean values.

Also, since you're building the query string dynamically, you also have to build the parameters array dynamically, so that the parameters match the placeholders.

```js
getUsers: (req, res, next) => {
  const queryParams = req.query
  logger.debug(queryParams)

  let {
    firstName,
    isActive
  } = req.query

  let queryString = 'SELECT * FROM `user`'
  let params = [];
  if (firstName || isActive) {
    queryString += ' WHERE '
    if (firstName) {
      queryString += '`firstName` LIKE ?'
      firstName = '%' + firstName + '%'
      params.push(firstName);
    }
    if (firstName && isActive) queryString += ' AND '
    if (isActive) {
      queryString += '`isActive` = ?'
      params.push(isActive == 'true' ? 1 : 0);
    }
  }
  queryString += ';'
  logger.debug(`queryString = ${queryString}`);
  logger.debug(`params = ${JSON.stringify(params)}`)

  dbconnection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) next(err) // not connected!

    // Use the connection
    connection.query(queryString, params, function(error, results) {
      // When done with the connection, release it.
      connection.release()

      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) next(error)

      // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
      logger.debug('#results = ', results.length)
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        results: results,
      })
    })
  })
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, though it still gives me the exact same result and once again does work if I replace the ? in the query with a hardcoded true or false

Comment: You have `firstName` in the parameters array even when there's no `firstName = ?` in the query string.

Comment: yeah that's it... there seems to be some unclarity in the documentation I am using about whether or not the user should be able to search with only one of the two values, it does work now though with the help of your code so thank you!